# Taking factors out of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, factoring

In the integral:
$$\int \left( \frac{-25}{17(2t+3)} + \frac{37}{17(5t-1)} \right) dt$$
Why is the final answer:
$$-\frac{25}{34} \ln|2t + 3| + \frac{37}{85} \ln|5t - 1| + C$$

If you take $-\frac{1}{2}$ as well as the $-\frac{25}{17}$ doesn't the fraction become: $$\frac{1}{t + 3/2}$$

And if you as well take the $\frac{1}{5}$ out of the other fraction shouldn't it become:
$$\frac{1}{t - 1/5}$$

I would have got a final answer of:
$$-\frac{25}{34} \ln \left| t + \frac{3}{2} \right| + \frac{37}{85} \ln \left| t - \frac{1}{5} \right| + C$$

Comment: For example the first integral: let $2t+3 = u$ then $dt = (1/2)du$ and consequently
$$\int \frac{-25}{17(2t+3)}dt = \frac{-25}{17} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \int \frac{du}{u} = \frac{-25}{34} \ln|2t+3|.$$

Comment: $\int\frac{-25}{17(2t+3)} + \frac{37}{17(5t-1)} dt$
=$\int\frac{-25}{17(2t+3)}dt +\int \frac{37}{17(5t-1)} dt$
=$\frac{-25}{17}\int\frac{1}{2t+3}dt+\frac{37}{17}\int\frac{1}{5t-1}dt$  
Well, you may interpret this as 'factoring out'.

Comment: We have $2t+3=2(t+3/2)$, so it would be $3/2$ instead of your $6$, and similarly $t-1/5$.

Comment: Your answer is now correct.

Comment: The very bottom one I edited?  Are you saying the solution provided by the website in this case was wrong?

Comment: Note that your revised answer (before the $+C$) is *different* from what you at the beginning called the final answer (before the $+C$). But the two differ by a constant, so the difference is taken care of by the constant of integration.  Both are right.

Comment: The answer is correct, move along now everyone, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding around integrals resulting in logarithms. Both answers are correct and equivalent.

$$-\frac{25}{34}\ln|2t + 3| + \frac{37}{85}\ln|5t - 1| + C_1$$

$$-\frac{25}{34}\ln|t + 3/2| + \frac{37}{85}\ln|t - 1/5| + C_2$$

To understand why note that: $$\ln|5t-1|=\ln|5(t-1/5)|=\ln5+\ln|t-1/5|$$ and $$\ln|2t+3|=\ln|2(t+3/2)|=\ln2+\ln|t+3/2|$$

So the two answers only differ by the constant $\frac{25}{34}\ln2+\frac{37}{85}\ln5$.

In other words the two constants of integration are not numerically equal and differ by this amount.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand this now.

Comment: Its a good one to remember. Sometimes you'll look at the answers the back of the book and think its wrong when its just written differently.

Comment: I think @TiernanWatson forgot to mark your answer as the right one. o_0

Answer (score 0):

$\int\frac{-25}{17(2t+3)} + \frac{37}{17(5t-1)} dt$ proceeds to be

$-\frac{25}{17}\int\frac{1}{(2t+3)}dt + \frac{37}{17}\int\frac{1}{(5t-1)} dt$

for the first integral, take $u = 2t+ 3$ so $du = 2 dt$. Then you get

$-\frac{25}{34}\int\frac{du}{(u)}$

for the second integral, take $u = 5t - 1$ so $du = 5 dt$. Then you get

$\frac{37}{85}\int\frac{du}{(u)}$

**HINT**

If you were to integrate the first integral, you would get $ln(u) + C = ln(2(t+\frac{3}{2})) = ln(2) + ln(t+\frac{3}{2}) + C$

Comment: Why is not possible then to take the factors out?  Realised I the factoring wrong and it should be $1/5$ and $3/2$, but this still isn't the same as when you do a $u$-substitution.

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Comment: But if you have $\frac{1}{2t+3}$ 1 is not the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying.

Comment: I thought you could only use $ln$ when the numerator was the derivative of the denominator, in the case of the $u$-substitution it is, but the website did this without $u$-substitution and I want to understand how: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Problems/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx number 2.

Comment: The author used the method of partial fractions because there is no u-substitution for the original fraction. Partial fraction decomposition results in a rational function that can be integrated using u-substitution. The resulting integral $\int\frac{du}{u}$ is integrated, resulting in $\ln(u) + C$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just "factor out" 2 from $ln(2t+3)$. You only can factor out exponents: $ln(a^x)=x\cdot ln(a)$

The integral of  $\frac{1}{at+b}$ is $\frac{1}{a}\cdot ln(at+b)+C$

The function $g(t)$ of $ln(g(t))$ is always the denominator of the derivative. But if you use the chain rule  $g(t)$ has also be differentiated. This $g'(t)$ has to be neutralized.

The derivative of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot ln(\underbrace{2t+3}_{g(t)})+C$ is equal to

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2t+3}\cdot \underbrace{2}_{g'(t)}$

Comment: You can indeed factor out $2$ from $ln(2t+3)$ according to the log rule $log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)$

Comment: I would not call it factoring out.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\left(\frac{-25}{17(2t+3)}+\frac{37}{17(5t-1)}\right)\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\int\frac{-25}{17(2t+3)}\space\text{d}t+\int\frac{37}{17(5t-1)}\space\text{d}t=$$
$$-\frac{25}{17}\int\frac{1}{2t+3}\space\text{d}t+\frac{37}{17}\int\frac{1}{5t-1}\space\text{d}t=$$

---

- Substitute $u=2t+3$ and $\text{d}u=2\space\text{d}t$.
- Substitute $s=5t-1$ and $\text{d}s=5\space\text{d}t$.

  ---

$$-\frac{25}{34}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u+\frac{37}{85}\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$-\frac{25\ln\left|u\right|}{34}+\frac{37\ln\left|s\right|}{85}+\text{C}=$$
$$-\frac{25\ln\left|2t+3\right|}{34}+\frac{37\ln\left|5t-1\right|}{85}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{37\ln\left|5t-1\right|}{85}-\frac{25\ln\left|2t+3\right|}{34}+\text{C}$$